How to read subprocess output before process completes
I'm working on a Python project that's making a subprocess.Popen call. That call will output strings before it completes. I want to read those strings in order to track progress.
Currently I'm doing it as such
with subprocess.Popen("<my command>", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, bufsize=1) as proc:
    while time.time() < timeout:
        line = proc.stdout.readline()
        ....additional work....

This works perfectly from a green path perspective, however it runs into issues if there's a problem. The reason being is that proc.stdout.readline() never times out and blocks the thread causing me to be stuck.
I've been reading the docs to explore other options but they all seem to rely on waiting for the process to finish before being able to read the output.
Does anyone have any suggestions for potential solutions?

Make sure the program flushes output after each line. By default, output to pipes is fully buffered.

If you can't change the program you're running, and you're on Unix, run it using unbuffer <my command>
